# Open webcam with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, webcam

I just want to know how to open webCam in Js but **i don't want any links to API or other libraries** because i make my own code always but can't find a way to go.I just want the one or two line code on how to open the webcam with js and want some description as how it work,in which browser it work.

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922723/using-a-webcam-with-javascript

Comment: Besides opening webcam in JS, do you have any other requirements? Such as image/video capture, image editing and uploading? As suggested below, it's better to use a third-party library such as Dynamic Webcam SDK. http://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/webcam-sdk.aspx

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I recommend you to use a third-party library like [ScriptCam](http://www.scriptcam.com/), but since you declared that you want to write your own code, I will give an explanation for using the new user media API.

It was introduced with the W3C Working Draft [HTML Media Capture](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html-media-capture-20100928/) with `getUserMedia()`. The following browser experimentally support it:

- Chrome
- Opera

In Chrome 18 or higher the API can be enabled visiting the `about:flags` site.

[image: Enabling the getUserMedia() in Chrome's about:flags page.]

In Opera you have to download one of the experimental [Android or desktop builds](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/labs-more-fun-using-the-web-with-getusermedia-and-native-pages/).

---

In HTML you will need to use the `video` Element

```
<video id="basic-stream" class="videostream" autoplay=""></video>
```

First you need to set the permissions:

```
navigator.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}, function(localMediaStream) {
  var video = document.querySelector('video');
  video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);

  // Note: onloadedmetadata doesn't fire in Chrome when using it with getUserMedia.
  // See crbug.com/110938.
  video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
  // Ready to go. Do some stuff.
  };
}, onFailSoHard);
```

If you want code that works in Chrome and Opera, the following code sample should do the work:

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;

var video = document.querySelector('video');

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true}, function(stream) {
    if (navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) {
      video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
    } else {
      video.src = stream; // Opera
    }
  }, onFailSoHard);
} else {
  video.src = 'somevideo.webm'; // fallback.
}
```

Whether the API is available can be checked with:

```
function hasGetUserMedia() {
   // Note: Opera builds are unprefixed.
   return !!(navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
        navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia);
}
```

Further information can be found in the tutorial [Capturing Audio & Video in HTML](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)

Syntax problems can arise from vendor prefixes, so look out for them.

Answer (score 2):

its quite new but its working:

http://www.scriptcam.com/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922723/using-a-webcam-with-javascript

http://chemicaloliver.net/internet/getusermedia-the-new-api-webcam-in-browser-using-javascript-and-html5-video/

Answer (score 1):

Requires Opera Mobile 12. If you add the webkit prefix it should also work in Chrome 21.

```
if(navigator.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.getUserMedia('video', successCallback, errorCallback);
}
```

See [the documentation](http://my.opera.com/core/blog/2011/03/23/webcam-orientation-preview).

Answer (score 1):

This is the so called [HTML5 Media Capture API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html-media-capture-20100928/). You will find sample code [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) for some mobile browsers.